# How exactly works this Angular 2 tutorial about custom event binding?

Tags: javascript, angular, javascript-framework

I am an absolute beginner with Angular 2 and I have some doubt about a tutorial example that I am studying about the **"binding to custom events"**.

So I have the main component that have this view named **app.component.html**:

```
<div class="container">
  <app-cockpit
    (serverCreated)="onServerAdded($event)"
    (blueprintCreated)="onBlueprintAdded($event)">
  </app-cockpit>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <app-server-element
        *ngFor="let serverElement of serverElements"
        [srvElement]="serverElement"></app-server-element>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Into this view is defined the inclusion of the  sub component that include this sub view in the previous main view, the **cockpit.component.html** file content:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <p>Add new Servers or blueprints!</p>
    <label>Server Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="newServerName">
    <label>Server Content</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="newServerContent">
    <br>
    <button
      class="btn btn-primary"
      (click)="onAddServer()">Add Server</button>
    <button
      class="btn btn-primary"
      (click)="onAddBlueprint()">Add Server Blueprint</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

That contains 2 button to submit the form.

Here the first doubt, from what I have understood doing something like:

```
(click)="onAddServer()
```

means something like: **"when the click event happen, perform the onAddServer() method defined into the controller of this view"**.

So, into the **coockpit.component.ts** class I have:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cockpit',
  templateUrl: './cockpit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cockpit.component.css']
})
export class CockpitComponent implements OnInit {

  /*
    EvebtEmitter è un oggetto del framework Angular che permette di emettere i nostri custom events
    @Output() decorator usato per passare qualcosa fuori dal component
   */
  @Output() serverCreated = new EventEmitter<{serverName: string, serverContent: string}>();
  @Output() blueprintCreated = new EventEmitter<{serverName: string, serverContent: string}>();

  newServerName = '';
  newServerContent = '';


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onAddServer() {
    this.serverCreated.emit({serverName: this.newServerName, serverContent: this.newServerContent});
  }

  onAddBlueprint() {
    console.log('INTO onAddBluePrint()');
    this.blueprintCreated.emit({serverName: this.newServerName, serverContent: this.newServerContent});
  }

}
```

That should works in this way:

The **newServerName** and **newServerContent** variable contains the data inserted by the user in the form because these variable are bound by **[(ngModel)]** directive:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="newServerName">
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="newServerContent">
```

When the user click on the **Add Server** button the **onAddServer()** method is perfromed and an event with **serverName** and **serverContent** content is emitted at the extern:

```
this.serverCreated.emit({serverName: this.newServerName, serverContent: this.newServerContent});
```

So a doubt is: what exatly is an event? It seems to me a simple Json object containing some information.

Then the second doubt is: the **serverCreated** event is emitted by this controller to the extern because it is deorate using **@Output()** decorator.

What is the default recipient? It seems to me that is the controller of the parent componet because in my **app.component.ts** class I have this method that handle this event:

onServerAdded(serverData: {serverName: string, serverContent: string}) {
    this.serverElements.push({
      type: 'server',
      name: serverData.serverName,
      content: serverData.serverContent
    });
  }

What exatly means the:

It is like I am saying that in the view of the main component I am saying that the **app-cockpit** component throw these event to the parent component.

Is it my reasoning correct or am I missing something? So it means that I can use this strategy only to pass an event from a child component to a parent component Or can I do the opposite (from parent to child, I don't know if it is a real use case scenario).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically right in your reasoning.

Coming specifically to your doubts:

1) When you emit an event, for instance in your case via `this.serverCreated.emit()` method call, you can pass as parameter of the the `emit()` method any object, and therefore also a pure javascript Json object. You could pass though any other object you can define as an instance of a Typescript class as well as any primitive type such as string or number

2) Events defined with the @Output() decorator can be listened by the Parent component and therefore are used as a mechanism to allow children components to talk to their parent component. The parent component can pass parameters to their children components via the symmetric @Input() mechanism.

You can get a complete list of methods for components to communicate among each other at https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction